# Количество подключений к БД на странице

Tags: php, mysql

Подключаюсь к БД с помощью следующего кода:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die("Could not connect");   
mysql_select_db("ttdb") or die("Could not select database");
```

Вопрос - сколько раз можно его использовать на странице?

Многие модули используют доступ к БД. И я везде тыкал этот код. Так можно делать, или его надо писать один раз на странице?

**Дополнено.**

Файлы с php-скриптами подключаются с помощью include. Если убрать из них приведенный выше код, поставить его в основной файл (выше includ'a), то в браузере, на месте подключаемого файла пишется ошибка:

> `Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in Z:\home...`

Comment: <?php  
    //Подключаем файл с подключением к БД  
    include 'mysql_connect.php';  
    //Подключаем файлы модулей  
    include 'module1.php';  
    include 'module2.php';  

Так должно работать, если все остальное верно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 соединение с mysql действует в пределах одного файла .php. Если к .php файлу подключить другой (с помощью include), то подключённому станет доступно подключение первого в пределах этого файла, от начала и до конца. При завершения работы скрипта (достигнут конец файла) соединение через `mysql_conect` разрывается.

Answer (score 0):

Если они все связаны (инклудом, например), то достаточно 1 раза.

Ежели у вас index.php, mod1.php, mod2.php никак не связаны, то да - необходимо в каждом модуле прописывать, но это нерационально.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше писать один раз. А в модули его отправлять при помощи `global $link.`
Если используете более сложную конструкцию для подключения(например, класс, вроде DBSimple), то можно вообще синглтон использовать.
Множество подключений сами по себе явного вреда не приносят: просто нагрузка больше, а контроля меньше

Answer (score 0):

В cms системах это реализовано через api

Comment: А можно поподробнее? Каким образом?